# How to get private variable from I18n yii?

Tags: php, yii, multilingual

I have a problem with multi languages from yii.

I want the admin be able to add any languages to my system.

Therefore I need get all country and region code languages from `i18n` `yii`.

That means I will display a dropdown list. It has all name languages. When I select any languages. it will auto generate region code.

Ex: I selected English, It will auto generate region code is **en**.

I tried `$languages = Yii::app()->locale->_data;` to get array. But because variable `$_data` is *private*.

This is code from Clocale class :

```
class CLocale extends CComponent
{
    public static $dataPath;
    private $_id;
    private $_data;
```

And here is code view I called:

```
$languages = Yii::app()->locale->_data;
var_dump($languages['languages']);
```

If I change private `$_data;` to `public $_data;` It will return result. But this is core from yii, therefore I can't change it.

Comment: extend the class so you won't have to change the core classes

Comment: @tinybyte 
can you description detail than?

Answer (score 1):

Parse folder names from messages directories

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

It's better than extend class and copy all its content (_data is private, so you can't access to it).

Comment: I don't clear your code.
I mean I want get all languages from i18n of yii.
We must get $_data to show it on dropdown list for user select.

Comment: The idea of Alex is right, just read the files, and that way you get the list of languages

Comment: you can't get _data, it's private. I suggest you to read language directories.